# Alternatives to UpdatePanel on a user control (ASCX page)

Tags: c#, ajax, user-controls, updatepanel

I am currently working on a ASP.NET AJAX application. Having decided to not use UpdatePanels for evident reasons, what alternatives to I have? This application has pages built dynamically and so most or all the components of the page exist as User Controls.

I need to make AJAX calls from ASCX user control page. And as ASCX user controls may not contain Page Methods, what other options do I have?

Or, is there a way to get around using Page Methods in ASCX page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way (that I discovered) is to
1. Place your PageMethods on the parent page 
2. When the PageMethod completes, let your user control know via a JS method that it can the PageMethod call has been completed
3. Then a ICallbackHandler can be implemented on the user control to do a AJAX callback on the user control's method

In my case, I need to update some values on the user control after the PageMethods gets executed, so I build my user control using HtmlOutputWriter to update the contents.

Works for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can't call webmethods from a `UserControl` as you said. The reason for this is methods marked with the `WebMethod` attribute must also be static. UserControls don't support this. If you aren't willing to use an `UpdatePanel`, you don't have a lot of options.

You could make `AJAX` calls via jQuery to `web services`? This would be one option...

`UpdatePanel` controls used with `UpdateMode="Conditional"` gives you fairly good control over what is happening with the callbacks and is still a reasonable solution. It won't be as lightweight as a straight ajax call but will be easy to maintain, etc.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery AJAX is my recommendation, used with web services provides a nice solution.