# Trigger user control post back from client side

Tags: c#, controls

Can a post back to the user control be triggered from javascript (on the client side) without updatepanels?

What I am trying to achieve is this

1. Initially the page and the user control are loaded with default values
2. The parent pages makes a PageMethod request
3. When the data is available (from the PageMethod request), the user control has to be reloaded to update with the new values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Alternatives to UpdatePanel on a user control (ASCX page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518829/alternatives-to-updatepanel-on-a-user-control-ascx-page/2592976#2592976)

Answer (score 1):

[Generating Client-Side Script for Postback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720099.aspx)
[Postback Using Client-Side Script Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720417.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

just call the preloaded function

you should find the following function in your rendered aspx page:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    theForm.submit();
}
}
```

Or if you are trying to make an ajax call, you can use the jquery library instead of the update pannel:

http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

or a demo to make an ajax enabled control

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/aspnetajaxcontroldevelopment.aspx

Comment: Can I make a Jquery Ajax call from a user control? My understanding is that it needs to refer to a PageMethod